# Embedded MailChimp Forms - Misbehaving when opened in Instagram Browser

Tags: instagram, mailchimp

I'm using an embedded MailChimp sign-up form.

Javascript is disabled on this form and I've set the page to redirect to a specific URL after a successful sign up. This works great when you sign up using a web browser.

However, when you open the website from instagram, the site renders in Instagram's own browser view. When you add your email address and click sign up, you are then redirected to a MailChimp hosted sign up page and have to enter your email address again.

Does anyone know of a way to prevent this?

Comment: Very nice your question, I too need of one response. Someone qualify?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Same problem here, have you solved it?

Comment: Just tried. Unable to reproduce this. Can you post the link here (or make a dummy one)?